# Best way to check checksum of bytes in python

Tags: python, crc

I receive some packets from serial port. Packet example:

```
                         last 2 bytes
                              /\
[ data length ] [ data ] [packet crc]
```

I get crc, for example, `b'w\x06'`. Value is 125 (`sum(b'w\x06') = 125`). I calculate crc of packet: `sum(data)`. And I get `1655`. I know that `1655` is the same as `b'w\06'`, but I do not know, how to translate it simply to `125` and compare with right checksum. What I need to convert `1655` to the same value as received packet bytes (`125` or `b'w\x06'`)? `binascii`/`struct`/something else?

Thanks

Comment: This is *not* a CRC - the math involved in that case is rather more complicated than `sum()`...

Comment: Okay, _sum of packet bytes_ is correct name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `int.from_bytes`:

```
int.from_bytes(b'w\x06', 'little')
```

or with `struct`:

```
struct.unpack("<H", b'w\x06')[0]
```

Comment: yes, so easy, I didnt look at right documetation :)